Не могу понять логики
Есть класс, в котором необходимо вернуть числа, в сумме дающие target. Не могу понять в чем проблема, потому что при работе выдает ошибку list index out of range.
Сами данные: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
        nums_copy = nums
        new_nums = []
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums_copy:
                if (nums[i] + nums_copy[j]) == target:
                    new_nums.append(i)
        return(new_nums)



Вам не нужны никакие копии списков

Требуется вернуть список с парой индексов, а не что попало

Индексы должны быть различными, т.е. для [2,1,3],4 нужно вернуть [1,2],а не 0 два раза



for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
        if (nums[i] + nums[j]) == target:
            return [i, j]

Такое решение даст верный ответ, но оно довольно медленное (квадратичное). Возможно, оно сойдёт для ограничений этой вводной задачи на литкоде. А для более быстрого решения (с линейной сложностью, но дополнительной памятью) можно использовать словарь, содержащий значения элементов как ключ, и индекс как значение

Да, спасибо вам огромное! Такое решение тоже подходит. Я просто попробовал себя в изучении задач на сайте, который вы упомянули (не стал писать название, вдруг репорт получу), довольно интересная штука. Изначально голова работала в правильном направлении, но никак не мог додуматься до использования словаря и последующей проверки на схожесть символов, как ключей, так и значений, ахах. Но все равно спасибо вам огромное

@Артем Квадратичное решение там не примут... С временем на выполнение на литкоде очень жестко.

Вот тут со словарём: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1576289/291659

Второй цикл от i+1 же должен быть. Иначе таки вернутся 2 раза одинаковые индексы, но в обратном порядке. Просто на другом каком-то примере.

@CrazyElf Совершенно верно, об этом и думал, но не то написал. Ещё собирался написать, чтобы автор обратил внимание, что второй цикл стартует с такого значения ;)

Как бы сказать, вы проходитесь напрямую по числам:
for i in nums:
    ...

Т.е. ваш цикл будет выглядеть так:
На первой итерации i=2, на второй i=7, на третьей i=11, на четвертой i=15. Уже на второй итерации i превысит длину списка и вызовет IndexError.
Понятное дело, что вам нужно проходиться по длине списка.
Для этого нужно создать последовательность от нуля до длины списка:
for i in range(len(nums)):
   ...

Таким образом, ваш цикл будет проходиться по индексам от нулевого до последнего.
То есть ваш код должен выглядеть так:
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
        nums_copy = nums
        new_nums = []
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums_copy)):
                if (nums[i] + nums_copy[j]) == target:
                    new_nums.append(i)
        return(new_nums)


Диагноз верный, а предложенное решение - нет.
